# Measure amount of data downloaded by ado.net/nhibernate

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, networking, ado.net

I'm working on WPF application that directly connects to SQL Anywhere database via NHibernate as ORM. Usually database is running on the same computer as application itself and local database is synchronized with main db server (via mobilink). However, when connecting to database over LAN or internet performance becomes bad. I would like to measure amount of data received by application from database. Anyone knows a good way to do this? I was thinking about some kind of listener for NHibernate/ado.net but not sure if this is possible. Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use [NHibernate profiler](http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/nhprof) to do that

Comment: I didn't find any information about amount of data download. I also checked NHibernate statistics and there were no such information too.